# Getting button appear after ListView has been set to invisible

Tags: android, listview, button

Thanks to some help from a user here I was able to hide my ListView when a button is pressed. What I want to happen is once I've pressed the button and it's hidden my ListView then the button outside the ListView tags to replace the space where the listview was.

Code below:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:fadingEdge="none">

    </ListView>
    <Button android:text="Arsenal" android:id="@+id/arsenal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> </Button>
```

Any help, once again is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE

Comment: Thanks for your answer - what I'd done is use VIEW.Invisible instead of VIEW.Gone which is what I needed to use - I think you wrote it the wrong way but thanks a bunch it helped me fix the issue.